# eclipse program stops at launching 27%

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator

i just installed eclipse 3.5.2 on my ubuntu 10.04 and also the ADT and the plugins for the android api.

When i first run an app lets say test.java it works great, but if i make a change and try to run it again the emulator doesnt works and at the down right corner displays this message :
**"Launching Test: (27%)"** and the emulator displays the program as it was without taking effect by the new changes.

[image]

You can check what i said at the right bottom of the pic.

thanx

Comment: This is a duplicate question, see the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410921/android-eclipse-stuck-launching-delegate-debugging-session-at-27

Comment: i managed to figure it out finally.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse gets stuck when trying to launch Android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118713/eclipse-gets-stuck-when-trying-to-launch-android-app)

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118713/eclipse-gets-stuck-when-trying-to-launch-android-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue happens when launching the first emulator from the Run button in Eclipse.

To avoid:

```
Start Eclipse
Window -> AVD Manager
Start an emulator
Run the project
```

Comment: Actually I've the same problem, but this can't solve my problem. (Eclipse Helios, Ubuntu 11.10)