# Android Eclipse Stuck Launching Delegate Debugging Session at 27%

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

Eclipse seems stuck at 27% "Launching MyProject (27%)"  is there anywhere eclipse might explain more.  I really don't have 30 minutes to watch this ...

I mean if there is something in its way could like a resource that it needs where does it indicate what the issue is during these long periods .........................

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse gets stuck when trying to launch Android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118713/eclipse-gets-stuck-when-trying-to-launch-android-app)

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118713/eclipse-gets-stuck-when-trying-to-launch-android-app

Answer (score 4):

see [Eclipse gets stuck when trying to launch Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118713/eclipse-gets-stuck-when-trying-to-launch-android-app)

When you start Eclipse.  Launch the emulator first (Window | AVD Manager | Start) and leave it running in the background.  Develop.

I do have the same problem when I forget to start the emulator first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried relaunching Eclipse and/or cleaning project?

When this happens to me I just close and open Eclipse again and it works

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem with 27% loading in eclipse indigo, then I start AVD and leave it running then I got solution of `27% hangout`....sometime it behave like hammering on our nails.
.......