# Eclipse launching delegate error in android

Tags: android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse gets stuck when trying to launch Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118713/eclipse-gets-stuck-when-trying-to-launch-android-app)

My android emulator is already running.
But when i make some changes in my project and again run the project in progress bar it shows me launching delegate and stuck on 27%.
and my eclipse also hang. i have to close eclipse and restart it.
Please suggest me solution.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of : [Eclipse gets stuck when trying to launch Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118713/eclipse-gets-stuck-when-trying-to-launch-android-app)

Just restart eclipse and start the emulator first (Window ! AVD Manager | Start or click on the toolbox icon showing an android inside a smartphone).  Leave it running in the background while you code, debug, etc.  It is what I do.

When I forget to do so, I get stuck at 27% too.

**Note**: you might have to reboot to kill the faulty process.  It was my case yesterday on Arch Linux...