# Eclipse Android debug doesn't work as expected

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, sdk, helios

I am using Eclipse Helios for 3 weeks and it was work very good. But it doesn't work normally for 2 days.

First of all, Eclipse stops at %27 when it the application launching on my second attempt. So, when the app works first time it is show me the emulator. But when I try to work the app a second time, it is stop %27 on launching.

Secondly, Eclipse did not debug my application. I add my breakpoints onto the app and try to open the debug mode. But it is not show the emulator on debug mode and did not give any error. Just saying `waiting the debugger for attach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid:

Start Eclipse
Window -> AVD Manager
Start an emulator
Run the project

also refer to 
[Eclipse gets stuck when trying to launch Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118713/eclipse-gets-stuck-when-trying-to-launch-android-app)

Comment: Ops, it doesnt work still for my another project. The debug mode opening and eclipse turn itself to debug mode, but the "green" line isnt show up. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Below two things will enable you to debug your application

1)Enable debugging in manifest file and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />
<application android:debuggable="true">
........
</application>
```

2)In emulator/phone Settings->Applications->Development->USB debugging(Check this check box)